# ¿Cómo saber si la respuesta del back cumple con una interfaz?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, arquitectura-de-software

Soy nuevo trabajando con arquitectura hexagonal.

He visto un video de un curso de [cómo aplicar arquitectura hexagonal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7siybJhBwx4&ab_channel=CodelyTV-Redescubrelaprogramaci%C3%B3n) y lo que hacen en dominio es crear un fichero por cada propiedad de la interfaz.

Dentro de cada fichero hay dos métodos:

- Uno que comprueba que si la propiedad cumple con su estructura o tipado.
- Otro en el que se lanza una excepción.

Mi duda es que yo obtengo una respuesta del back y por ejemplo tiene 15 campos.

¿Tengo que crear un fichero por cada propiedad o existe alguna forma de mapear si la respuesta cumple con la interfaz?

En angular he visto que hay mappers pero en react no he visto nada de mappers, ¿existe alguna librería para ello? o como se podría hacer un mapper.

Por ejemplo esta interfaz.

```
interface User {
  uid: string;
  name: string;
  lastname: string;
  age: number;
  email: string;
  phone: number;
  address: string;
  picture: string;
}
```